# Is this decryption function idiomatic?

Tags: string-manipulation, code-review, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

This is my first non-trivial Mathematica notebook, which I wrote for a cryptology homework. It encrypts/decrypts strings using an affine cipher. Is the code readable/idiomatic? How could it be improved? (I'm using version 10, so I don't have the `ModularInverse` function).

```
toNum[c_] := LetterNumber[c] - 1

toChar[n_] := Alphabet[][[n + 1]]

encryptAffine[m_, b_] := StringJoin[
   toChar[
      Mod[m toNum[#] + b, 26] 
      ] & /@ Characters[#]
   ] &

decryptAffine[m_, b_] := StringJoin[
   toChar[
      Mod[
       PowerMod[m, -1, 26]*(toNum[#] - b),
       26
       ]
      ] & /@ Characters[#]
   ] &

decryptAffine[3, 7][encryptAffine[3, 7]["helloworld"]]


(* "helloworld" *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressive enough for my taste. But a bit shorter and *much* faster (by 3 orders of magnitude) would be to use `ToCharacterCode` and `FromCharacterCode` as follows:

```
decryptAffine2[m_, b_] := FromCharacterCode[
    Mod[PowerMod[m, -1, 26] (ToCharacterCode[#] - (97 + b)), 26] + 97
    ] &;

f = decryptAffine[3, 7];
g = decryptAffine2[3, 7];
s = StringJoin[RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 10000]];
r1 = f[s]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r2 = g[s]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r1 == r2
```

> 1.28523
>
> 0.000329
>
> True

`ToCharacterCode` has the advantage that it transforms a string into a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496). Moreover the arithmetic operations are vectorized so that they can applied componentwise to arrays. This often provides enormous speedup compared to using `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, hadn't heard of that function!